# How to handle Mongoose Cannot populate path is not in your schema error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

> MongooseError: Cannot populate path `friends` because it is not in your
> schema. Set the `strictPopulate` option to false to override.

I have the following code:

```js
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   age: Number
})
const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'users')
```

and then in one of the controllers I have the following code:

```js
UserModel.find({ name: 'Isaa' }).populate('friends');
```

The above line results in the following error:

> MongooseError: Cannot populate path `friends` because it is not in your
> schema. Set the `strictPopulate` option to false to override.

I want to handle this error in my express error handling middleware, but how?
The error doesn't have any unique field that I can use, such as `error.code` or `error.name`.
So How to handle this error?

```js
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    //  here
})
```

Comment: How about `error.message`?

Comment: @hoangdv, it's weird